# Grails: How to query objects in many to many mapping?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

Hello I have the follwing domain classes.

```
class Student {
   int age
   static hasMany = [courses:Course]
}

class Course {
   String name
   static hasMany = [students:Student]
}
```

I want to find the Students taking Course (with id 1), with age 7.

Could I do that with dynamic finder or criteria builder or HQL?

I do not want to do following as it load all students so inefficient:

```
def course = Course.get(1);
course.students.findAll{ it.age == 7 }
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
def studs = Student.withCriteria {
  eq('age', 7)
  courses {
    eq('id', 1)
  }
}
```

It's in [GORM doc](http://gorm.grails.org/6.1.x/hibernate/manual/#_querying_associations_3), section "Criteria/Querying Associations".

Answer (score -2):

You can use a dynamic finder:

```
def students = Student.findByCourseAndAge(Course.load(1), 7)
```

By using `load()` instead of `get()` you avoid retrieving the whole Course instance and just reference its id.

Another option is HQL:

```
def students = Student.executeQuery(
   'from Student s where s.course.id = :courseId and s.age = :age',
   [courseId: 1, age: 7])
```

Comment: Hello Burt. Student does not have "course" field, it has "courses". I can not do findByCourse, I can do findByCourses but it may I compare collections.